# SAP GUI scripting in Python, sapguiauto.GetScriptingEngine does not return any Object

Tags: python, win32com

I am running the following SAP GUI script using python.  I am SAP session open, but I am not getting application information using GetScriptingEngine.

**My code**

```py
import sys, win32com.client

sapguiauto = win32com.client.GetObject("SAPGUI")
print(sapguiauto)

sapapplication = sapguiauto.GetScriptingEngine
print(sapapplication)
```

**Error**

```
C:\Users\a4fhbzz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/a4fhbzz/PycharmProjects/untitled/ILM/SAPGUI/TestLogonSAPGUI.py

COMObject SAPGUI>

COMObject unknown

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Should you maybe be calling the `GetScriptingEngine` function? `GetScriptingEngine()`...

Comment: Thank you Justin.

Comment: AKX, I tried GetScriptingEngine() but I am getting pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352573, 'Member not found.', None, None)